# LibreOffice is saving CSV files with tabs as separators

Tags: csv, libreoffice

I just opened a CSV file in LibreOffice, made a small change and hit save, saying "yes, keep using CSV". The file is now filled with tabs instead of commas. My scripts (using Python's CSV lib) won't read it and I have go out of my way to replace tabs with commas.

Just to be clear: a CSV file by very definition uses commas, otherwise it'd be a TSV file, right?

Is there some option in LibreOffice I can set to make it use commas when writing CSV files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For some users (thoses using KDE), the "edit filter settings" box is gray. A workaround is to use Openoffice dialogs. Tools > Options > LibreOffice > General > Open/Save dialogs > Use LibreOffice dialogs[image]
Then you will be able to choose the field delimiter wanted.[image]
That bug was reported here : https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72187

Comment: 7 years later, on Ubuntu 20.04 (on Gnome) I was hit by this issue. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 16):

When you export a CSV file, go to *File > Save As*, select *Text CSV* as file type and then go to *Edit filter settings*.

In this dialog you can select the cell delimiter and change it from Tab to a comma.

Comment: Under "file->export", there's only `xhtml` and `pdf`. In "file->save as" there's `csv` but the checkbox for "Edit filter settings" is greyed out and no further related dialogue boxes show.

Comment: There should be "Text CSV" as depicted here: http://www.csvimproved.com/images/tutorials/libreoffice_saveas.png — it's also explained on the LibreOffice wiki: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files

Comment: I have that window, unfortunately my "Edit filter settings" is disabled just like your "Save with password". I can only guess there's some conflicting option somewhere. I'll keep trying, but thanks for your time!!

Comment: You don't export to csv, you save as csv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that when you **opened** (i.e. **imported**) the CSV file, you had both Tab and Comma enabled as separators:

[image: import dialog]

With that, LibreOffice will unfortunately use tabs as separators when writing/exporting (even if the original file contained only commas, not tabs).  If you uncheck Tab at import time, it will preserve the commas on export.